# Piping output of process to file asynchronously in windows

Tags: windows, logging, cmd

I am trying to run a program using "start" and I want to have the output piped to a txt file, for example, I want to have the output of a simple http python server to be logged to a text file:

```
START cmd /c python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000^>engineLog.txt
```

The above will print it to the log file but the problem with that is, it only prints it when the process finishes. Are there any way that I can store it to the log as it is running? Also is it possible to have it log in the txt file as well as having it print out in the console?

Comment: Maybe it's that the application has to flush its output stream for the write to happen? I'm not entirely sure, but I would assume that to be the case. So unless you can force the application to flush its streams in some way, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save logs - SimpleHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360798/save-logs-simplehttpserver)

Comment: @MarkW, fortunately in this case Python has a `-u` option to make stdout unbuffered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
START /b "Your title" "cmd /c python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 > engineLog.log | type engineLog.log"
```

Alternatively, you can [get](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) `tee` port for Windows.